# Disapper old shape when new shape is made in processing

Tags: processing, shapes

I want to make the old shape disappear when the new shape is made. Please help me. Basically, I want to create a rectangle on click but when I click again circle should disappear. This should happen with equal probablity.

```java
void setup()
{
    size(400, 400);
    background(255);
}

void draw()
{
    fill(255);
    tileAp();    
}

void tileAp()
{    
    if (mousePressed && mouseY >= 0 && mouseY <= 200)
    {    
        drawM(true);
    }
    else
    {    
    }
}

void drawM(boolean b)
{
    int prob = int(random(0, 2));
    if (b == true)
    {
        if (prob == 0)
        {
            rect(mouseX, mouseY, 50, 50);
        }

        if (prob == 1)
        {
            ellipse(mouseX, mouseY, 50, 50);
        }    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Like the [suggested duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35551272/how-to-remove-previous-shape-after-draw-in-processing) says, you need to call the `background()` function to clear out old frames.

Compare this sketch:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/processing.js/1.6.6/processing.min.js"></script>
<script type="application/processing">

void setup(){
  size(200, 200);
  background(64);
}

void draw(){
 ellipse(mouseX, mouseY, 20, 20);
}

</script>
<canvas> </canvas>
```

To this one:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/processing.js/1.6.6/processing.min.js"></script>
<script type="application/processing">

void setup(){
  size(200, 200);
}

void draw(){
 background(64);
 ellipse(mouseX, mouseY, 20, 20);
}

</script>
<canvas> </canvas>
```